# Ubuntu started asking for my password in more cases (mounting, updating)

Tags: updates, mount, permissions, security, udisks

I am using this computer and Ubuntu installation for a long time, and I upgraded to 16.04.1 two months ago. A few days ago though, Ubuntu started asking me for my password in some cases that it didn't use to before.

One of the cases is whenever I connect any USB drive. I have tried with an external HDD (NTFS) and with flash drives. The same when I try to eject a drive. Simply a window like this appears:

[image]

I thought there was only a problem with mounting, but I also get it when I run the Software Updater (even to update the cache):

[image]

When I run `apt update` (without sudo), I also get permission errors:

```
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Why could this have happened suddenly? Was there an settings change by an upgrade?

Any ideas how to make it less strict again?

*edit: I re-wrote my question since by now I have observed the problem better.*

Comment: More than likely something changed permissions or ownership of the external drive. What backup program/procedure are you using? How do you mount the drive in Ubuntu? At what mount point? Does the drive mount properly in Windows? Let me know. Cheers, Al

Comment: Thank you for your interest, I rewrote my question with more details!

Comment: It looks like it was fixed the same way it started: suddenly, by itself. But I will keep an eye on this.

Comment: Isn't it funny how a reboot can clear up problems? Cheers, Al

Comment: It is, but unfortunately this got many reboots and the reason it started as well as the reason it (hopefully) stopped are totally unknown to me at the moment...